# I want to find the month name of 2018 where there are 5 Sundays or more

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

My problem is to find the month name of 2018 where there are 5 Sundays or more... I cannot do it. Does anyone has an idea how to solve this ?

Comment: This is a simple math problem: https://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/823-years.html#first

Answer (score -1):

You can just count it:

```
from collections import Counter
from datetime import date, timedelta

SUNDAY = 6
c = Counter()

for i in range(365):
    day = date(2018, 1, 1) + timedelta(days=i)
    if day.weekday() == SUNDAY:
        c[day.month] += 1

# prints {4, 7, 9, 12}
print({month for month in c if c[month] >= 5})
```

Comment: i want the month names

Comment: There can be 366 days in a given year, so you should have one loop between 1-12 and another one up to the last day of the month (see `monthrange`). But other than that, this is a bad question, where the asker just wants some code with no effort or attempt made, so it should not be answered.